# Using data only after fetching JSON information

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I'm setting in a ViewController a NSString property by fetching a JSON table and then in a different ViewController I want to get that same property.

What is happening is when I'm trying to get the property this is nil.

I know what is the problem, I'm accessing the property in the main thread while the JSON fetching is still in progress in another thread.

I'm using the AFNETWORKING 2.0 framework to access the JSON table.

How can I wait for the property set and then use it?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: it will have success block and failure block. use them. It will be much helpful, if you post the code of download here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in different ways, you can post notification from `AFnetworkingJSON` operation `success` callback like this. And observer that notification where you want to access that `property`. You can also pass a `completionHandler` to the method which can be call from success or failure callbacks.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"link"]];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        // Post notification from here
// call completion handler if you have any
    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response,

    }
];

[operation start];
```